# Activity transition not working properly with background color

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two Activities (A and B) in my app. Both activities have a background color. When I open Activity B from Activity A using an intent, for a moment background color changes to the default grey color. This flash of default color makes it so the transition doesn't look smooth. How can I make it smooth?

Activity A XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#116493" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity B XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#116493">

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity A.java

```
package com.example.test;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tt1;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L,timeToGo=0L,startTime=0L;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    }
    public Runnable updateTimerThread=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeToGo = 30 - (timeNow - startTime) / 1000;
            tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tt1.setText(timeToGo+"");
            if(timeToGo<0L){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Game.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else
                customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
}
```

Activity B .java

```
package com.example.test;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Game extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    }


}
```

Comment: can you post activityB code?

Comment: Done @GennadiiSaprykin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In Activity A i have used finish() before starting another intent. So the previous Activity closes first and next is opened. There is a momentary lag between execution of these two activities and it is seen as a default grey color flash. This is due to fact that at that short time no activity is present and default color is flashed.

I solved the problem by starting intent first and then finishing previous activity using finish.

The code of Activity A is

```
package com.example.test;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tt1;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L,timeToGo=0L,startTime=0L;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    }
    public Runnable updateTimerThread=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeToGo = 30 - (timeNow - startTime) / 1000;
            tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tt1.setText(timeToGo+"");
            if(timeToGo<0L){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Game.class);
                startActivity(intent); //Exchanged the order of statement
                finish();              //After starting intent
            }

            else
                customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing too many calculations on the UI thread, that's why it is lagging. Especially `findViewById` is a very heavy operation. Try this instead:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tt1.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "");
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // tt1.setText("done!");
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Game.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
     }.start();
 }
```

Comment: Still transition is not smooth. Flash of grey in between.

Comment: Do you use any flags in AndroidManifest.xml for Game activity?

Comment: No, but found the solution

Comment: Then post your solution here and accept it as an answer

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your problem. But I still recommend using `CountDownTimer` because the code will be cleaner. Or, at least, don't do `findViewById` all the time.. Also, accept your own answer to this question since you resolved it. Thanks.